# How to increase the head size of a specific type of arrow in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to edit some arrows properties in matplotlib. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do with my dataset. I know how to edit some properties using *arrowprops* when dealing with the "normal" arrow (that one in *test1*), but I need to point to an interval between two points on the line. For this, I need to increase the size of the arrow's "head" in *test2*. Basically, I need the head of this arrow to cover/point to the interval between the points (5.0, 3.5) and (4.0, 3.0).

Below is my code and its output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))

plt.plot([1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4], marker='o')    

ax.annotate('test1', (2, 2.1), xytext=(-15,15), color='r', size=13, 
            textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(width=0.3,
                                                        headwidth=5,
                                                        headlength=4,
                                                        shrink=.18),
            bbox=dict(pad=0.01, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'))

ax.annotate('test2', (5, 3.3), xytext=(20,-40), color='r', size=13, 
            textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-['),
            bbox=dict(pad=0.01, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'));
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) states that some keys are forbidden if the `arrowsprops` dict contains `arrowstyle`. Hence, to increase the arrow's head size, you must use the `mutation_scale` key.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5, 5))

plt.plot([1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4], marker='o')    

ax.annotate('test1', (2, 2.1), xytext=(-15, 15), color='r', size=13, 
            textcoords='offset points', 
            arrowprops=dict(width=0.3, headwidth=5, headlength=4, 
                            shrink=.18),
            bbox=dict(pad=0.01, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'))

ax.annotate('test2', (4.8, 3.1), xytext=(10,-60), color='r', size=13, 
            ha='center', va='center', textcoords='offset points', 
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-[', mutation_scale=28, 
                            connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.38'),
            bbox=dict(pad=0.01, facecolor='none', edgecolor='none'));
```

I also added the `connectionstyle`, `horizontalalignment`, and `verticalalignment` parameters to make it easier to align the arrow's head with the line. But please keep in mind that they are optional.

**Final result**:

[image]